# How to create a custom event that triggers when a variable changes

Tags: javascript, web-component, custom-events

I am creating a custom widget with JavaScript and I need to create an event that triggers when a user changes a checkbox, for now I have a click event, but that doesn't work for what we want.

So I thought that creating a Custom Event is the way to go, and my idea is, I already have a variable that gets the value of the item that is selected, so I wanted to create a custom event that listen to this value and when it changes it will trigger the event. Don't know if this is the best way to do this, but this is my idea.

```
  this.addEventListener("selectedItem", event => {
    var eventSelectedItem = new CustomEvent("SelectedItem");
    console.log(selecteditem);
  })
    
function selecteditem(selectItem) {
  const selectedItem = _SelectItem // this is the variable that gets the value of the selected Item
    
    // now I don't know what to do here, I am reading a few things but this is the first time I am creating a custom event; 

    // I tried setters and getters but that I didn't understood how to make that work; 

    // Basically I need to save the last value and get the new value and then dispatch the event;
  
  selectItem.dispatchEvent(selecteditem);

}
```

Any help would be appreciated, either a new idea, or how to create this.

---

Edit to include more info.

```
let tmpl = document.createElement("template");
tmpl.innerHTML = '<div style="" id="root"></div>';

        class MultiInput extends HTMLElement {
          constructor() {
            super();
            
            _shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
            _shadowRoot.appendChild(tmpl.content.cloneNode(true));
        
            this._export_settings = {};
        
            this.addEventListener("click", event => {
              var eventclick = new Event("onClick");
              this.dispatchEvent(eventclick);
            }); // This event works, but it triggers on all clicks (ofc) but it is not the event that I want
    
            this.addEventListener("change", event => {
              var eventchange = new Event("onChange");
              this.dispatchEvent(eventchange);
              console.log("Event is triggered");
            }); // This works only on textbox that I also have in the widget
          }
        }
```

Comment: The value of the variable won't change unless something changes it. Why would something change the value of the variable? Usually in response to an event, like a click, change, or input event. I don't think using custom events is going to help you here.

Comment: "*I need to create an event that triggers when a user changes a checkbox, for now I have a click event, but that doesn't work for what we want.*" - you probably should use the `change` event for that, not the `click` event. But regardless, can you tell us which code would listen to this custom event from the widget and how?

Comment: @Bergi Basically the widget is creating a List of items that the user can select each one (multiple or single select) and I need to have a event for when the user changes the selection, but the change Event doesn't work for the "checkbox" or "radioButton" it works for the "textbox" we have there. So my idea was to listen to the variable that gets the value of each selected item.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I also found that post, and I couldn't make it work =/ kinda of a newbie in this

Comment: @DanielSantos "*the change Event doesn't work for the "checkbox" or "radioButton"*" - can you show us the code where you tried that please?

Comment: @Bergi 
`this.addEventListener("change"), event => {`
  `var eventchange = new Event("onChange");`
  `this.dispatchEvent(eventchange); `
  `codeconsole.log("test");`
`}`
I tried that, the textbox triggers the console.log, but the checkbox or radiobutton doesn't, if I use "click" instead of "change" it also works

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show exactly how you hooked up the change event. The code in your comment would not work due to a syntax error. It's also difficult to know what `this` refers to without context.

Comment: @HereticMonkey done, please check the changes, thanks and sorry for not including everything

Comment: @DanielSantos Can you also show what `tmpl` is and how you use that `<MultiInput>`? I'm missing a [mcve] that I can run myself

Comment: Aha, you're creating a web component. Very important information to have. You're adding the event to the host element, which means it catches all events triggered within the host. Try using event delegation (e.g., `if (event.target.type == 'checkbox') { /* create event and dispatch */ }`).

Comment: @Bergi done, tmpl is to create a document.createElement("template"); I edited the code again

Comment: @HereticMonkey I was reading about event delegation, but there is a few problems one is that single select instance of the widget doesn't have an input, it has a svg that changes visual... 

This is why I wanted to have an event that would check if the "getSelectedItems" would change values. I talked about a variable because I gave the "getSelectedItems" value to a variable, and this changes when a user selects a item from the list.

Comment: Basically set a click event, when a user clicks on an item, if the selecteditem changes then dispatchEvent something like that? would that work? I don't know how to get the last selectedItem and compare it to the new value. Maybe with setters and getters?

Comment: Please use the [<>] button in the editor and create an executable SO snippet. That way we don't have to extract what you actually want from all comments (and make people write answers you are not after)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you mean, this is simpler than creating an event. You just need to add the code in the function

```js
document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("change", event => {
      // Add your code here
  })
})
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="Hello">
<label for="Hello">Hello</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="World">
<label for="World"`enter code here`>World</label>
```

Comment: I really need an event because I am developing a widget for a low code application, so I need to develop an event for when the user wants to add something in the application for when the selection change. I tried change event but it only listen to the searchbar textbox, not the input checkbox or radio button. So that is why I wanted to check if the value of the variable that gets the selection value changes.

Comment: I tried with change with the checkbox and it works perfectly, but ok I'm sorry if I didn't get what you meant

Answer (score -1):

Well, with proxies you can track properties:

```js
let obj = {
  myValue: 1
}

let proxy = new Proxy(obj, {
   get(obj, prop) {
      return obj[prop]
   },
   set(obj, prop, val){
      console.log("value changed")
      obj[prop] = val
   }
})


setInterval(() => {
   proxy.myValue++
},1000)
```

The `set` function is your trigger event, whenever you change your value `proxy.myValue`

Whenever the property value gets changed, the `set` function fires

Comment: No need for a proxy here, a setter/getter for the property would suffice